# What is the proper file naming convention of class extension in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for my class. It has private properties declared in the class extension. Now, I would like to provide access some of these properties in my unit tests, hence I have to extract the class extension from the implementation file into a separate header file that I can import in my unit tests. What is the proper file naming convention of class extension when it's separated from the implementation (.m)?

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end

// MyClass.m
@implementation MyClass
@end

// MyClass+???.h
@interface MyClass()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;

@end
```

Comment: Why would you separate the extension from the implementation? It is pretty common to declare something public in you header file and then declare all the rest you need in the implementation file just above the implementation. If you need some extra public API, you'd better use categories.

Comment: @Danchoys I would like to reach those properties in my unit tests only. So, it would break the API design if I declare them as public just because I would reach them from the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard code convention for Objective C. Apple's documents describe only few simple moments. The most common approach is to use

```
MyClass_Private.h
```

for extensions and

```
MyClass+Private.h
```

for categories.

Comment: Yep, it seems this is a common convention for "standard" categories, but what about class extension? `MyClass+Private.h` would indicate that this is a category.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard. Name the file something appropriate. The contents are supposed to be 'Private' and are only there to enable testing so that would be a suitable (and relatively standard) name.

Comment: I agree with this, but what would be appropriate? I have a bad feeling that it would be confusing if I call it `MyClass+Testing.h`, because this is an integral part of the implementation.

Comment: I recommended 'Private'. I agree 'Testing' is a very bad choice.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use `MyClass+CategoryName.h` when the extension is a category, but if the extension is not a category then I call it `MyClassExtension.h` or `MyClass_extensionName.h`